# Moving Files in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Is there a way to move files from one library to another and maintain version history?  We have Sharepoint Designer as a resource, but nothing else.

Comment: This question was already asked here http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/1278/how-can-you-move-a-document-with-its-version-history-to-a-new-library/1292#1292

Comment: Thanks Lars.  There are lots of good options on that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to do this programmatically you will need Visual Studio, as this cannot be done with SharePoint Designer.

Alternatively, use the Content Deployment Wizard which Rob suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Content Deployment Wizard that is available on Codeplex.com for free, there is an option to copy including revisions. Did you need to do it programmatically?  If not, this should work for you.

Comment: Yes, I would like it to copy files and versions programmatically.

Comment: Well, normally I would say you could write code in Visual Studio to do this, but since you only have SharePoint Designer you'll need a different solution.  One solution would be to use PowerShell.  There are a few SharePoint Powershell packages on CodePlex that offer list copy functionality.  You could tweak the scripts to fit your need.  Most of them first export the source list to a temporary file location, then import it from the temp location to the target list.  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428301.aspx for guidance on writing your own.  It discusses revisions.

Comment: Also, there is an action in SharePoint Designer for copying list items, but I don't believe it will copy the revisions with it.  Depending on the nature of your application (do you need all past revisions or just revisions going forward) this may work for you if revision history is also turned on in the target list.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the File Explorer ('Open With Windows Explorer' in the Document Library's Action Menu). It maintains version history the last time I checked.